# field 'obj' has incomplete type note: forward declaration of 'class B'

Tags: class, friend, forward

I have seen before in stack overflow classes can friend each other. Here I am doing class A and class B friend each other. But when I create an object in A class for B its throws an error which is "*field 'obj' has incomplete type note: forward declaration of 'class B*'". I also declared class B with forward declaration. But it's not working.

How can I solve it? Thanks for your Help!

```
#include<iostream>
class B;
class A{
    friend class B;
    B obj;
    public:
        int x = 199;
        
};

class B{
    friend class A;
    A obj;

};

int main(){
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had said `B * obj;`, it would work.  The problem is that, without having the full declaration before hand, the compiler does not know how large `B` is, and thus cannot establish a size for `A`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have some questions now. I create a B class pointer with this: B * obj;?  If I am right, 1. Now, how compiler know What the size of B  is?  2. How I am doing full declaration here. Thank you!

Comment: If you do `B * obj;`, the compiler doesn't NEED to know how large a B is.  It just needs to make room for a pointer, and all pointers are the same size.  It only needs the details when you try to use the B*.  The design you have above cannot be made to work.  You can't have an A contain a B and a B contain an A; that's infinite recursion.  But an A can contain a B* and a B can contain an A*.